# com.sun.servicetag.*. is missing from my eclipse luna IDE

Tags: java

I want to obtain the system hardware information using

```
import com.sun.servicetag.SystemEnvironment
```

But it is missing. How can I fix this?

Comment: The `com.sun` package must be from the JDK/JRE. Check the JDK/JRE mapped to your eclipse project and make sure it is the one you really need.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little research on your part and this is what I uncovered. `com.sun.servicetag` is a package meant solely for "Sun internal use". [This link](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/servicetag/package-index.html) confirmed the same to me.

The doc says that this package is used to "allow the creation and manipulation of service tags" and public availability of those packages could lead to serious security issues.

EDIT: Hold the horses! Further research did lead me to [this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.scn/sysnet-registration/1.0.1/com/sun/servicetag/SystemEnvironment.java) which gives you what you want. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanx! But how do i get the whole com.sun.servicetag integrated into my eclipse. i want make an app that gets system information.